# CORS support in WebAPI, MVC and IIS with Thinktecture.IdentityModel

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am trying to implement CORS using Thinktecture.IdentityModel as mentioned in the link below:

http://brockallen.com/2012/06/28/cors-support-in-webapi-mvc-and-iis-with-thinktecture-identitymodel/

I tried Web API method and it didn’t work. So I went towards IIS route.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests=“true“>
    <add name=“MvcCorsHttpModule“
         type=“Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Http.Cors.Mvc.MvcCorsHttpModule“/>
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

And then again in global.asax you would configure the settings:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    …
    RegisterCors(MvcCorsConfiguration.Configuration);
}

private void RegisterCors(MvcCorsConfiguration corsConfig)
{
    corsConfig
        .ForResources(“Products.GetProducts”)
        .ForOrigins(“http://foo.com&#8221;)
        .AllowAll();
}
```

Now, it works in my local host (Windows 8, VS 2012) but when I push it to prod (IIS 6), it doesn’t work. Is there other settings to make it work in IIS 6? Why would it work in the localhost but not when I push it to production.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the inverse of [this](http://blog.dczweb.net/post/Migration-of-ASPNET-app-from-IIS6-to-IIS7-%2875%29.aspx).

Modules are registered differently in IIS6 to IIS7+.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <httpModules>
        <add name="MvcCorsHttpModule" type="Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Http.Cors.Mvc.MvcCorsHttpModule"/>
      </httpModules>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```